# Reducing subset sum to zero weight cycle

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, np-complete

I'm trying to convert an instance of zero subset sum to zero weight cycle in directed graphs to prove that the ZWC problem belongs to the np-complete class. My solution: for each element like x in the zero subset-sum array, create a node in graph G and add an edge from this node to all the other nodes in the graph with weight x. Then if this graph contains a zero weight cycle, our zero subset sum has a solution and vice versa. 
But when I searched for the solution on the web I found a different way of constructing the graph.

[the solution I found on the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmDih.png)

Now the question is that are there any problems with my reduction algorithm?

Comment: Your construction fails for $\{0\}$ but I can't think of a non-trivial counterexample

Comment: @Akababa So, to resolve this issue maybe we can add self-loops so that zero elements can be detected since self-loops are cycles too.

Comment: Yes, adding a self loop with weight x will resolve the issue.